# Word mail merge errors in "by category"

Tags: ms-word, docx-mailmerge, fieldcodes

Please see the attachments for the mail merge issue. The result expected by me should have been:

[image]

But it turns out to be:

[image]

I believe the error is caused by the comparison in the field codes (i.e. <>) but I couldn't figure out where the error is. If I make a change to the data,

**1A --> F1A**
OR
**1A --> A1**

The error disappears. Here are the **field codes**:

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put double quotation marks around `{ Place2 }` and `{ Place1 }`, e.g.

```
"{ Place2 }"
```

As it is, when word does the comparison, it will evaluate values such as 1A, 2D etc. as the numbers 1 , 2 etc. Since your list starts with 1A, 1C, the comparison will be `{ IF 1 <> 1 }` so the transition from 1A to 1C will be missed.

If you want to ensure that Word does a *textual* comparison, this is one reason. In fact in this scenario Word treats things that look like simple arithmetic expressions as such so if Place1 was called `"2*4"` and Place2 was called `"8"`, you would get a match if you did not include the quotation marks.

There are other reasons why it is advisable to quote the comparands in an IF field when you want them to be treated as text. For example if you have the following, X is definitely `"abc"` and Y is definitely `"def"` .

```
{ SET X "abc" }{ SET abc "def" }{ SET Y "def" }{ X }{ Y }
```

But this will return "equal"

```
{ IF { X } = { Y } "equal" "not equal" }
```

whereas this will return "not equal"

```
{ IF "{ X }" = "{ Y }" "equal" "not equal" }
```

In other words, if a comparand is not quoted and evaluates to the name of a bookmark in the document, it is treated as a reference to the bookmark value and is dereferenced.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!